# SiteCatalyst 15 - Video Tracking, s.Media.open() and .play() not working! I need a working example

Tags: flash, video, tracking, adobe-analytics

I use SiteCatalyst 15 and installed AppMeasurement.swc in our Flash Video Player.

I followed the steps in the omniture documentation.
“Measuring Video for Web Analysts”
http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/video/index.html#Measuring_Video_for_Web_Analysts

Also, I copied the following codes as the starting point. 
“ActionScript Sample Code”
http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/video/index.html#ActionScript_Sample_Code

When I test the video player, s.track() is actually working and sending parameters to the SiteCatalyst Server, but s.Media.open() and s.Media.play() are not working.

I am little confused what was wrong with my AS3.0 codes, so I would like to find any working example of flash video tracking.

Thank you for your help.